# Highlight search results - whole expressions and single words

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want highlight whole expresions and single words

```
$text ="text text aaa bbb ccc text aaa text xxaaayy text bbb ccc text bbb cccxxx text";
$words = array('aaa bbb ccc','aaa bbb','bbb ccc','aaa','bbb','ccc');
foreach ($words as $k=>$v){
  $text = preg_replace('/(\w*?'.$v.'\w*)/i', '[b]$1[/b]', $text);
}
```

this code will return:

**text text [b][b]aaa[/b] [b]bbb[/b] [b]ccc[/b][/b] text [b]aaa[/b] text [b]xxaaayy[/b] text [b][b]bbb[/b] [b]ccc[/b][/b] text [b][b]bbb[/b] [b]cccxxx[/b][/b] text**

how to get this result:

**text text [b]aaa bbb ccc[/b] text [b]aaa[/b] text [b]xxaaayy[/b] text [b]bbb ccc[/b] text [b]bbb cccxxx[/b] text**

how to modify preg_replace ?

Comment: You likely need to use assertions `(?<!` and make the regex search for all word groups at once `aaa|bbb|aaa bbb` instead of in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go :

```
<?php

$text ="text text aaa bbb ccc text aaa text xxaaayy text bbb ccc text bbb cccxxx text";
$words = array('aaa bbb ccc','aaa bbb','bbb ccc','aaa','bbb','ccc');
$text = preg_replace('/('.implode("|",$words).')/i', '[b]$1[/b]', $text);
echo $text;

?>
```

**UPDATED Version:**

```
<?php

$text ="text text aaa bbb ccc text aaa text xxaaayy text bbb ccc text bbb cccxxx text";
$words = array('aaa bbb ccc','aaa bbb','bbb ccc','aaa','bbb','ccc');
$text = preg_replace('/(\w*('.implode("|",$words).')\w*)/i', '[b]$1[/b]', $text);
echo $text;

?>
```

Comment: I have one small problem with this, 

it don't work with special chars for example like this
...text aaaóa text ....
preg_replace return:
...text [b]aaa[/b]óa text ....
how to modify it, file is in utf-8, data is from mysql in utf-8 too

Comment: @user2117559 my answer is the correct one for your question you should accept the answer, you can also replace \w with \p{L} to match utf-8 characters